# vicar vs pastor

Tags: word-usage

In the novel *The Island of Desire* by American beachcomber and writer Robert Dean Frisbie, the tiny atoll of Pukapuka (Cook Islands) has both a pastor and a vicar, and the difference in their tasks isn't clear at all to me. The pastor has a rather pretentious stone built vicarage, and the vicar is the local shopkeeper... My problem is that I have to translate this into French, where the vicar translates as "le curé" and the curate translates as "le vicaire". Help!

Comment: The text of the book suggests that the parson is higher level than the vicar.  "parson" is usually a Protestant term; vicar can be Catholic.  They both seem to be of the same religion/denomination in this book, which I just skimmed quickly; both have unconventional views of their religion.

Comment: [christianity.se]